# How to use experimental meshing API with Project Tango

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, google-project-tango

I apologize in advance for my long post.

My purpose is to create a meshing app for a Project Tango Yellowstone device to create a 3D map of building interiors.  I intend to make use of the experimental meshing API added in recent versions of the tango-examples-c code.

**I'm using point-cloud-jni-example (turing) as a starting point and so far have done the following:**

1. Set config_experimental_enable_scene_reconstruction tango config parameter in point_cloud_app.cc (see [docs](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/c/reference/group/config-params?hl=en))

   ```
   // Enable scene reconstruction
   ret = TangoConfig_setBool(tango_config_, 
           config_experimental_enable_scene_reconstruction", true);
       if (ret != TANGO_SUCCESS) {
           LOGE("PointCloudApp:         config_experimental_enable_scene_reconstruction() failed"
               "with error code: %d", ret);
           return ret;
   }
   ```
2. Added extractMesh native method in TangoJNINative.java

   ```
   // Extracts the full mesh from the scene reconstruction.
   public static native float extractMesh();
   ```
3. Added matching extractMesh function to the jni_interface.cc

   ```
   JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
   Java_com_projecttango_experiments_nativepointcloud_TangoJNINative_extractMesh(
   JNIEnv*, jobject) {
       app.ExtractMesh();
   }
   ```
4. Added ExtractMesh method in point_cloud_app.cc

   ```
   void PointCloudApp::ExtractMesh() {
   // see line 1245 of tango_client_api.h
       mesh_ptr = new TangoMesh_Experimental();
       TangoService_Experimental_extractMesh(mesh_ptr);
       mesh = *mesh_ptr;
       LOGE("PointCloudApp: num_vertices: %d", mesh.num_vertices);

       float float1, float2, float3;
       float1 = mesh.vertices[1][0];
       float2 = mesh.vertices[1][1];
       float3 = float1 + float2;  // these lines show I can use the vertex data
       LOGE("PointCloudApp: First vertex, x: %f", mesh.vertices[1][0]);  // this line causes app to crash; printing the vertex data seems to be the problem
   }
   ```
5. Added TangoMesh_Experimental declaration to point_cloud_app.h

   ```
   // see line 1131 of tango_client_api.h
   TangoMesh_Experimental* mesh_ptr;
   TangoMesh_Experimental mesh;
   ```
6. Added an additional button to call the extractMesh native method.  (not showing this one as it is pretty straightforward)

**For reference, here is the TangoMesh_Experimental Struct from the [API](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/blob/master/tango_client_api/include/tango_client_api.h#L1131):**

```
    // A mesh, described by vertices and face indices, with optional per-vertex
    // normals and colors.
    typedef struct TangoMesh_Experimental {
    // Index into a three-dimensional fixed grid.
    int32_t index[3];

    // Array of vertices. Each vertex is an {x, y, z} coordinate triplet, in
    // meters.
    float (*vertices)[3];

    // Array of faces. Each face is an index triplet into the vertices array.
    uint32_t (*faces)[3];

    // Array of per-vertex normals. Each normal is a normalized {x, y, z} vector.
    float (*normals)[3];

    // Array of per-vertex colors. Each color is a 4-tuple of 8-bit {R, G, B, A}
    // values.
    uint8_t (*colors)[4];

    // Number of vertices, describing the size of the vertices array.
    uint32_t num_vertices;

    // Number of faces, describing the size of the faces array.
    uint32_t num_faces;

    // If true, each vertex will have an associated normal. In that case, the
    // size of the normals array will be equal to num_vertices. Otherwise, the
    // size of the normals array will be 0.
    bool has_normals;

    // If true, each vertex will have an associated color. In that case, the size
    // of the colors array will be equal to num_vertices. Otherwise, the size of
    // the colors array will be 0.
    bool has_colors;
    } TangoMesh_Experimental;
```

My current understanding of this struct is:

1. The three pointers in `float (*vertices)[3];` point to the addresses at the start of three chuncks of memory for the x, y, and z coordinates for the vertices for the mesh (the same is true for normals and colors colors).  A specific vertex is composed of an x, y, and z component found at a specific index in the three arrays.
2. Similarly, the `uint32_t (*faces)[3]` array has three pointers to the beginning of three chunks of memory, but a specific set of three elements here instead contains index numbers that indicate which three vertices (from the vertices array (each with three coordinates)) make up that face.

**The current status is I am able to extract the mesh, and print some of it to the console, then crashes without errors**

```
PointCloudApp: PointCloudApp: num_vertices: 8044
```

If I omit the last line I added in point_cloud_app.cc (#4, above), the app doesn't crash.  I am able to access the vertex data and do something with it, but printing it using LOGE causes a crash 9 times out of 10.  Occasionally, it does print the value correctly without crashing.  Could the vertex data have holes or invalid values?

I have tried returning test_float from JNI back to java, but it crashes again when I try to do so.

Suggestions?

Comment: _"Suggestions?"_ - Properly initialize the arguments you are passing to the function - i.e. **don't** pass it a null pointer value, it doesn't accept it. Fix your code instead of worrying about modifying their code.

Comment: Thanks, @CaptainObvlious.  I got it working by adding this line `mesh_ = new TangoMesh_Experimental();` in point_cloud_app.cc, before the call to `TangoService_Experimental_extractMesh(mesh_)`.

Comment: Now stuck on retrieving vertex data.

Comment: Then post another question if you need help.

Answer (score 1):

`vertices` is a dynamic array of points, where each point is a `float[3]`. Try this example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mesh.num_vertices; ++i) {
  printf("%d: x=%f y=%f z=%f\n", i, mesh.vertices[i][0], 
      mesh.vertices[i][1], mesh.vertices[i][2]);
}
```

If you look at the memory layout, it would be x0 y0 z0 x1 y1 z1 etc, each of those a float.

Comment: Thanks Ivan! I updated the question to use the double brackets.  I can access the vertex data and do something with it (see changes in step 4), but when I try to print vertex values using LOGE, the app crashes.  I am able to print other float values fine.  Interestingly, it does print successfully about 1 out of 10 times without a crash.  Could the floats in the vertex data be different than the floats LOGE expects?  This really has me stumped.

Comment: I would suggest checking the return value of the `TangoService_Experimental_extractMesh` call

Comment: I am trying to look at variables, but need to get [ndk debugging working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193244/cant-debug-ndk-samples-with-android-studio-1-3-2-on-windows) first (not an easy task!).  Once I can look at the contents and type of mesh.vertices[1][0] in the debugger, I think things will make more sense.

Comment: @IvanDryanovski Im getting error on line `mesh.vertices` : `Array type expected , found 'java.nio.FloatBuffer'` . Any guidance how to fix this ?