# Can't debug NDK samples with Android Studio 1.3.2 on Windows

Tags: android, c++, debugging, android-studio, android-ndk

I have Android Studio 1.3.2, NDK r10e, gradle experimental plugin 0.2.0.  I have  cloned the [ndk samples repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk.git) and carefully followed instructions for the [NDK Preview](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview), including creating a Native configuration.

When I select LLDB as the debugger and debug the Teapot NDK sample app (breakpoint in TeapotNativeActivity.cpp, line 393), the app runs, but breakpoint isn't hit as it should when I rotate the teapot.  Using GDB for the debugger results in the app freezing on startup.  I then have to force quit the app and press stop in the debugger window.

In both cases, debug controls appear (greyed out), and the variables window says, "Connecting", but I never see the "Waiting for Debugger" dialog on my device.

Console output using LLDB:
[image]

Console output using GDB:
[image]

Now, when I do the same thing from Android Studio 1.4 Preview 3, I now get the "Waiting for Debugger" dialog, but it hangs there.  It looks like the debugger never connects.

Console output Android Studio 1.4:
[image]

Is it possible to debug with AS 1.3.2 or 1.4?  What do I need to do next to get it working?

Comment: I installed Android Studio 1.3 (stable channel) on Lubuntu 14.04, added a new native debugging configuration and was finally able to debug the C++ code (using LLDB) in the latest teapot sample.

Comment: Since it worked on Linux with Android Studio 1.3, I thought I'd try that version on Windows, but it still wouldn't stop at my breakpoints in C++.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to Android Studio 1.4 beta and the issue is fixed.  I can now debug my C++ code.

Comment: that's lame that it's still not working for 1.3 while it was promised. First we need to depend on Gradle Experimental for lated NDK integration and now a beta version of Android Studio ? Sure, let's all be crazy in here !

Comment: @Nate, on which OS platform your android studio 1.4 is running ?

Comment: Android studio 1.4 is running on Windows 8.1

Comment: windows7sp1, android studio 1.5 and experimental:0.4.0  ,I now get the "Waiting for Debugger" dialog, but it hangs there. It looks like the debugger never connects.